# 'Row Goal' different behavior - why?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008, performance, optimization, query-performance

This is a heap with 400+ Million rows and 16 non clustered indexes, 146 columns. Please do not focus on why I cannot create a clustered index. That is not in my control and not in scope to my question.

SQL Server:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR) (KB4057116) - 11.0.7462.6 (X64)   Jan  5 2018 22:11:56   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor) 
>   Database Compatibility Level:SQL Server 2008(100)

When I run following query (anonymized), I get [this actual execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJfSfTP5H):

```
SELECT TOP ? *
FROM Schema1.Object1 Object2
WHERE Object2.Column1 LIKE ?
ORDER BY Object2.Column2 DESC
```

Same database restored to SQL 2017 CU13 and change compatibility mode to SQL Server 2012 (110) (following is the full version name), and I get [this actual execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkBBWpwqB).

> Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU13) (KB4466404) - 14.0.3048.4 (X64)   Nov 30 2018 12:57:58   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

I totally understand that 'ROW GOAL' is in play here. You cannot see it in the first plan as it was not exposed in the query plan before. To be sure I can run the SQL Server 2008 version with **Trace Flag 4138** and SQL Server 2012 version with `DISABLE_OPTIMIZER_ROWGOAL` hint. Both cases I get significant performance gain. Gain happens because optimizer pick the right index and does not choose a `nested loop join`.

Question:

- While both compatibility level is prior to SQL Server 2014 version why `EstimatedRowsWithoutRowGoal` (I understand you cannot see it in 2008) is different?
- Why Index Scan qualify 1.1 Million rows in SQL 2008 vs 8.7 Million rows in SQL 2012? What heuristics changed (even I am not using new optimizer launched with Compatibility 120)?

I read [this article](https://sqlperformance.com/2018/02/sql-plan/setting-and-identifying-row-goals) by Paul White and all 8 links given in the article.
Also read [More Showplan enhancements – Row Goal](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/more-showplan-enhancements-row-goal/) by Pedro Lopes

Comment: Is `Object2.Column2` unique? Is the ordering guaranteed to be the same across instances?

Comment: Object2 is alias for object1. Object2.Column2 is not unique. Ordering should be guaranteed as we restored from backup.

Answer (score 4):

**Your 2 queries (and tables?) don't exactly match.**

The sql server 2008 compatibility level query has **143 columns returned** while 
the sql server 2012 compatibility level query  **has 146 columns** returned.

Please validate any other differences in these tables.

---

> Why Index Scan qualify 1.1 Million rows in SQL 2008 vs 8.7 Million
>   rows in SQL 2012?

Your index scan is returning rows, ordered by `Object2.Column2` 
to then push their bookmark

(bookmark=`column144` / `Column147` in your anonomized plans)

to the RID lookup and filter on `Object2.Column1`.

---

**Initial guess: Ties?**

This leads me to believe that `Object2.Column2` has ties, resulting in different rows to be read first.

Both are executing ordered prefetching

```
  <NestedLoops Optimized="0" WithOrderedPrefetch="1">
```

> ... An ordered prefetch preserves key order on the inner side of the
>   nested loops join,  so SQL Server ensures that asynchronous I/Os are
>   processed in the correct order. ... Our test query features an ORDER BY
>   clause that the optimizer can avoid sorting for by using ordered
>   prefetch...

[Source](https://www.sql.kiwi/2013/08/sql-server-internals-nested-loops-prefetching.html)

I might be wrong, but what I take from this is that, as long as the ordering is preserved, different rows could be fed to the **RID** lookup operator, supporting the ties claim.

You could try running the query with a unique order and adding these query plans to the question.

---

> While both compatibility level is prior to SQL Server 2014 version why
>   EstimatedRowsWithoutRowGoal (I understand you cannot see it in 2008)
>   is different?

We would need detailed statistic information here. The statistics show different estimates between the tables, resulting in a difference in `EstimatedRowsWithoutRowGoal`

You could try running a full scan update before running both queries while selecting the same amount of columns.

---

**Testing**

When doing tests between sql server instances (2008) & (2017 with compat 2012)

I keep on getting the same amount of rows returned:

2008 (compatibility):

[image]

[Query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SycV8wd9r)

2012 (compatibility):

[image]

[Query Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkWrIwO9r)

Even when changing Column2 to hold many duplicates, the estimates & actuals remain the same.

```
UPDATE dbo.Object1
SET Object1.Column2
= Object1.Column2 % 400;
```

As expected, estimates remain the same when adding the extra columns to the table in the compat 2012 db

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Object1 
ADD ExtraColumn1 int default(1) with values;
ALTER TABLE dbo.Object1 
ADD ExtraColumn2 int default(2) with values;
ALTER TABLE dbo.Object1 
ADD ExtraColumn3 int default(3) with values;
```

Same story with enabling the traceflags

**Conclusion**

This kind of rules out my previous statement about ties in your data, but also shows that I cannot replicate your problem with my dataset (much smaller).

Even if I set the entire `column2` to the same value, there is 0 difference in the amount of rows returned. Data differences seem like what should cause this.

---

**Dataset used**

```
CREATE DATABASE TEST
GO
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TEST] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'TEST', FILEGROWTH = 1048576KB )
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TEST] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'TEST_log', FILEGROWTH = 1048576KB )
GO
alter database test set recovery simple
GO
backup database test to disk = 'NUL'

GO

use TEST
go

CREATE TABLE dbo.Object1(
Column1 int,
Column2 int,
Column3 int,
Column4 int,
Column5 int,
Column6 int,
Column7 int,
Column8 int,
Column9 int,
Column10 int,
Column11 int,
Column12 int,
Column13 int,
Column14 int,
Column15 int,
Column16 int,
Column17 int,
Column18 int,
Column19 int,
Column20 int,
column1_varchar varchar(20));

CREATE INDEX Index1
on dbo.Object1(column15,Column16,Column17)
 CREATE INDEX Index2
on dbo.Object1(Column2,Column10,Column19)


SELECT top(1000000)  --1M
row_number() over(order by (select null)) as rownum
INTO #temp
FROM master..spt_values spt1
cross apply master..spt_values spt2
cross apply master..spt_values spt3


INSERT INTO dbo.Object1
WITH(TABLOCK)
SELECT 
rownum,
rownum,
rownum,
rownum,
rownum,
rownum,
rownum,
rownum,
rownum,
rownum,
rownum,
rownum,
rownum,
rownum,
rownum,
rownum,
rownum,
rownum,
rownum,
rownum,
'ABC'+ CAST(rownum as varchar(20)) 
FROM #temp  
GO 3
```

Comment: Randi thank you. I created this chat room to discuss further. Do you know how to start a conversation there?https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/201659/row-goal-different-behavior-why?tab=general

Answer (score 1):

Randi Vertongen's answer is best I can expect based on the information I gave in my original question. I am ONLY writing this as an answer as I cannot put this in comment for other readers. 
Disclaimer: Randi and I chatted about this [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201659/row-goal-different-behavior-why).

Once piece of information will help you to follow along. In my top 100 result set with where clause all result belongs to value `829000514900` from column2.

Data set is totally different in the heap between the two environment. 
I decided to do a rolling sum based on column2.

Here is what I found. I believe the small differnece still exist is due [`Forwarded Record][2]` in heap.

I ran below query in both environment.

```
SELECT 
    column2, 
    COUNT(0) AS CountColumn2, 
    SUM (COUNT(column2)) OVER (ORDER BY column2 DESC) AS RunningTotal
FROM dbo.object1
GROUP BY column2 
ORDER BY column2 DESC
```

Result for SQL Server 2008 environment:

> actual number of row read=1176085

```
colum2          CountColumn2    RunningTotal
829000515000    79              1175804
829000514900    159             1175963
829000514800    631             1176594
```

Result for SQL Server 2012 environment:

> actual number of rows read=8891415

```
colum2          CountColumn2            RunningTotal
829000515000    79                      8892962
829000514900    159                     8893121
829000514800    631                     8893752
```